GitHub Actions - Successful Workflow Run, But No Files Copied to Server
I've tried multiple times to copy my repo files to server after pushing to main branch,
No files are being synced..
Im quite new to the github actions..
Following is my yaml.
name: Deploy to cPanel

on: push: branches: - main

jobs: deploy: runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - name: Checkout code
    uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: List files in GitHub workspace
    run: ls -al ${{ github.workspace }}
  
  - name: SSH and execute commands
    uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
    with:
      host: ${{ secrets.CPANEL_HOST }}
      username: ${{ secrets.CPANEL_USERNAME }}
      key: ${{ secrets.SSH_CPANEL_KEY }}
      passphrase: ${{ secrets.SSH_PASSPHRASE }}  # Only include this if your private key is encrypted
      port: ${{ secrets.CPANEL_PORT }}
      script: |
        rsync -avz --delete-after --exclude '.*/' --exclude 'access-logs' --exclude '.cagefs' github_workflow/

Any guidance is appreciated..
